# kotlin nested threads - "there is more than one label with such a name in this scope"

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

I have some kotlin code similar to this:

```
Thread {
    ...
    Thread {
        ...
        return@Thread
        ...
    }.start()
    ...
}.start()
```

Now I get the following warning:

[image]

I understand that kotlin is confused as to which Thread I want to return at this point, whether it's the outer or the inner thread. But I'm not sure how to tell it and Android Studio doesn't help much either, as it only suggests editing the options for this warning:

[image]

I have tried naming the thread and thought maybe kotlin is smart enough to check for that, but I guess this might not be possible, because the return label is probably not interpreted on runtime.

I realize that I can just export the inner thread into a function and thereby have the threads not interfere with each other, like this:

```
Thread {
    ...
    startInnerThread()
    ...
}.start()

fun startInnerThread() {
    Thread {
        ...
        return@Thread
        ...
    }.start()
}
```

But I would like to know if it's somehow possible to change the label `@Thread` for one of them instead.

Comment: Yea, you can label the line that you want to return to, with `Foo@` at the start of the line, and then use `return@Foo` if I recall correctly. I used the name `Foo` to make it obvious you can call this return label anything you want (so no, Foo isn't some magic word :D )

Comment: See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you can do what I suggested in hindsight, so read the official docs and have a play

Comment: @ThomasCook looks like it works and the link you posted suggests that too. Ill mark your answer as accepted as soon as SO allows me to :)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Yea, you can do this by labelling the function to return from like so:

```
Thread {

    Thread Foo@ {

        return@Foo

    }.start()

}.start()
```

Comment: Don't just book it Thomas Cook it! Thanks