# How to resolve label conflict in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How do I fix the label conflicts that occur in kotlin?

Example :

```
        var cnt = 0;
        val correctMap = Array(8) {
            Array(8) {
                if (cnt < 20) {
                    cnt++
                    return@Array 1 // label conflict
                } else {
                    0
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin nested threads - "there is more than one label with such a name in this scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774815/kotlin-nested-threads-there-is-more-than-one-label-with-such-a-name-in-this-s)

Comment: This is just a sample code. In general if I have label conflicts what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a named label with the `label@` syntax:

```
val correctMap = Array(8) outer@ {
    Array(8) {
        if (cnt < 20) {
            cnt++
            return@outer 1
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove return keyword

```
 val correctMap = Array(8) {
            Array(8) {
                 if (cnt < 20) {
                    cnt++
                     1 
                } else {
                    0
                }
            }
        }
```